# error: too few arguments argparse

Tags: python, json, firebase

I'm trying to import a json file into firebase using a python script. Then I came across a similar script in Github. I tried running it after the replacing the required parameters. I'm getting a too few arguments error. This is the Github project if you would like to refer

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-streaming-import

Snippet of the code I'm running is given below. I'm using IDLE to run the program. Thanks in advance

```
argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Import a large json file into a Firebase via json Streaming.\
                                                 Uses HTTP PATCH requests.  Two-pass script, run once normally,\
                                                 then again in --priority_mode.")
argParser.add_argument('firebase_url', help="Specify the Firebase URL (e.g. https://test.firebaseio.com/dest/path/).")
argParser.add_argument('json_file', help="The JSON file to import.")
argParser.add_argument('-a', '--auth', help="Optional Auth token if necessary to write to Firebase.")
argParser.add_argument('-t', '--threads', type=int, default=8, help='Number of parallel threads to use, default 8.')
argParser.add_argument('-s', '--silent', action='store_true',
                       help="Silences the server response, speeding up the connection.")
argParser.add_argument('-p', '--priority_mode', action='store_true',
                       help='Run this script in priority mode after running it in normal mode to write all priority values.')

main(argParser.parse_args())
```

Comment: How are you running this? It seems, that you have two mandatory arguments, did you provide them?

Comment: Yes, i did give two arguments

Comment: Could you specify? I copied that code, ran it and had no problem.

Comment: First argument was the link to my database and the second one is my json file. You can see that i have put some dummy values in the code above.

Comment: Yes I see, what I'm asking is the command how you run this code? This should be something like `python program.py arg1 arg2`

Comment: No, i ran it using IDLE

Comment: Ah OK, I have no experience with that, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot parse arguments with parameters like in terminal/cmd in IDLE. Try parsing the args as such : `args = argParser.parse_args(['URL','FILE_PATH'])`

```
import argparse

argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Import a large json file into a Firebase via json Streaming.\
                                                 Uses HTTP PATCH requests.  Two-pass script, run once normally,\
                                                 then again in --priority_mode.")
argParser.add_argument('firebase_url', help="Specify the Firebase URL (e.g. https://test.firebaseio.com/dest/path/).")
argParser.add_argument('json_file', help="The JSON file to import.")
argParser.add_argument('-a', '--auth', help="Optional Auth token if necessary to write to Firebase.")
argParser.add_argument('-t', '--threads', type=int, default=8, help='Number of parallel threads to use, default 8.')
argParser.add_argument('-s', '--silent', action='store_true',
                       help="Silences the server response, speeding up the connection.")
argParser.add_argument('-p', '--priority_mode', action='store_true',
                       help='Run this script in priority mode after running it in normal mode to write all priority values.')

args = argParser.parse_args(['URL','FILE_PATH'])

print(args)

main(args)
```

Output:

```
Namespace(auth=None, firebase_url='URL', json_file='FILE_PATH', priority_mode=False, silent=False, threads=8)
```